# Upload attachment using Corda shell not working?

Tags: corda

Trying to upload file using the following command in terminal:

```
run uploadAttachment jar: /abc.jar
```

It generates error:

```
run uploadAttachment jar:: command not found
```

[Using these docs.](https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-attachments.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is in an error in the documentation. It should be either:

```
run uploadAttachment jar: ./abc.jar
```

Or:

```
run uploadAttachment jar: abc.jar
```

If the file cannot be found, you will get the following exception:

```
Could not parse as a command: <jar-path>
```

Comment: /upload endpoint is not available in spring web server. How to upload file with it?